# Hardcode JSON Array in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have two variables from two different SQL queries that I want to put in to one JSON Array (i.e `$hometown` and `$topcat`).  I am trying to hardcode it but not sure how it's suppose to look.

```
   print(json_encode('{"hometown":"' . $hometown .'", "category":"'. $topcat .'"}'));
```

My output is this:

```
{\"hometown\":\"Seattle, WA\", \"category\":\"Movies\"}"
```

Not sure where the slashes are coming from (I suppose I can to do stripslashes?) and it seems I need to add '[' and ']' as well?  What is the proper formatting for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) takes your array or object, it doesn't accept strings that are already JSON encoded. It can be done like this:

```
print json_encode(array('hometown' => $hometown, 'category' => $topcat));
```

Outputs

```
{"hometown":"Seattle, WA","category":"Movies"}
```

Comment: The first sentence is false. It is correctly encoding the provided string – that's just not what the OP wants.

Comment: It encodes strings as strings, even if it's valid JSON, it doesn't encode them to a JSON object or array, hence the backslash escaping.

Comment: That's true, but that doesn't make the first sentence of your answer true.

Comment: Thanks; I noticed when I output most JSON Array's, they do have the '[]' brackets surrounding them, this doesn't.  Are those needed?

Comment: A Javascript array is different to PHP arrays. JS arrays can't have associative keys like in PHP, they are numerical keys. Using the `[]` syntax is for when you don't care about the keys, for example a list of values. For example try `print json_encode(array('apple', 'orange', 'banana'));` It will output JSON with the `[]` syntax like: `["apple","orange","banana"]` because the array elements don't have associative keys so the array can be safely encoded into a Javascript array.

Answer (score 4):

That string already looks like JSON; why are you trying to encode it again?

> Not sure where the slashes are coming from

Because that code encodes a *string* that contains double-quotes, which must be escaped in JSON.

Unsafe, and dumb, but easy solution:

```
print('{"hometown":"' . $hometown .'", "category":"'. $topcat .'"}');
```

Better solution:

```
print(json_encode(array(
    'hometown' => $hometown,
    'category' => $topcat,
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The string is already formatted as a JSON object, encoding is what is adding the slashes. The `json_encode()` function is made to convert arrays to JSON objects not strings also whats with the `print()`, `print()` is deprecated and `echo()` should be used.

Here is your solution:

```
echo '{"hometown":"'.$hometown.'", "category":"'.$topcat.'"}';
```

Comment: Yes I know but I mean't that it is formatted as a JSON object.